# Which Newsletter popup Component is best for joomla?

Tags: joomla3.0, newsletter

I am looking a Newsletter component for free but it should have Popup module please suggest me.

Comment: This question is probably better suited to http://joomla.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

## AcyMailing

Everyones needs are different but the answer to "Which Newsletter Component is best for Joomla?" is usually [AcyMailing](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/acymailing-starter). AcyMailing Starter is free and basic features are included. The commercial versions add [additional features](https://www.acyba.com/acymailing/features.html) such as spam testing, bounce back handling, additional third party integrations and so on.

The AcyMailing subscribe module can be popup enabled using a free or paid popup extension (see below).

## Other Free Solutions

[jNews](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/marketing/newsletter/jnews) and [BwPostman](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/marketing/newsletter/bwpostman) are other free full newsletter solutions including newsletter subscription modules similar to AcyMailing but these solutions also need an additional module to implement the modules as popups (see below).

[Newsletter Subscriber](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/marketing/mailing-a-distribution-lists/newsletter-subscriber) and [SJ Newsletter Popup](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/style-a-design/popups-a-iframes/sj-newsletter-popup) are simpler newsletter  subscription modules but Newsletter Subscriber needs an additional module to implement the module as popups (see below).

### Paid Popup Extensions

- [aikon Magic Popup](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/aikon-magic-popup) is not free but is inexpensive and has some excellent features such as load delay and exit triggers that aren't necessarily found in the free popup extensions.

### Free Popup Extensions

- [Engage Box](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/style-a-design/popups-a-iframes/engage-box)
- [Auto onPageLoad Popup](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/style-a-design/popups-a-iframes/auto-onpageload-popup)

## Other Ideas

For other ideas and the latest information, search the [Joomla Extensions Directory](https://extensions.joomla.org).